# Change [object Object] to string in angular 2 download csv

Tags: angular, csv

[image: my csv]

I got some problems in my data download csv, i want [object Object] change to string in file csv. but i have try code the result is undefined.


**this is my JSON format, i only take one example data**

```
[
  {
    "id": 117,
    "code": "RR123",
    "dueDate": "2018-06-25T09:51:00",
    "isActive": true,
    "inspectors": {
      "id": 67,
      "employeeNumber": "18001",
      "name": "Larks Anderson",
      "isActive": true
    },
    "questioners": {
      "id": 63,
      "code": "PI190",
      "name": "Inspeksi Door",
      "isActive": true,
      "questionerDetails": [
      {
          "id": 124,
          "questionDetail": "",
          "isActive": true
        }
      ]
    }
  },
]
```

**This is my code in component.ts**

```
//Button CSV
getcsvFile() {
  this.workorderService.getAllWorkOrder().subscribe(data => {
    this.allpagingData = [];
    let questionerlabel: any;

    for (let index in data) {
      console.log(data[index].questioners);

     //i use this to change the [object Object], but the result is undefined in csv
      for (let ai in data[index].questioners) {
        questionerlabel = data[index].questioners[ai].name;
        console.log(questionerlabel);
      }

      this.allpagingData.push({
        "code": data[index].code,
        "inspectors": data[index].inspectors,
        "questioners": questionerlabel,
        "dueDate": data[index].dueDate,
        "isActive": data[index].isActive
      });
    }
    var option = {
      fieldSeparator: ',',
      quoteStrings: '"',
      decimalseparator: '.',
      showLabels: true,
      showTitle: true,
      headers: ['WO Code' , 'Inspectors', 'Questioner', 'Date', 'Status']
    }

    new Angular2Csv(this.allpagingData, 'WorkOrder Report', option)
  });
}
```

so how to change [object Object] to string?

Comment: What parameters are accepted by Angular2Csv function?

Comment: Angular2Csv is module from angular, i used module and import { Angular2Csv } from 'angular2-csv/Angular2-csv'; on the top my component.ts

Comment: the parameters are accepted is (any,string,any)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert your 'inspectors' into a string. So use JSON.stringify(object) like this:

```
    this.allpagingData.push({
    "code": data[index].code,
    "inspectors": data[index].inspectors ? JSON.stringify(data[index].inspectors) : '',
    "questioners": questionerlabel ? questionerlabel : 'N/A',
    "dueDate": data[index].dueDate,
    "isActive": data[index].isActive
     });
```

For just inspector's name:

```
    this.allpagingData.push({
    "code": data[index].code,
    "inspectors": data[index].inspectors ? data[index].inspectors.name : '',
    "questioners": questionerlabel ? questionerlabel : 'N/A',
    "dueDate": data[index].dueDate,
    "isActive": data[index].isActive
     });
```

Comment: ok thank you, it's worked. but how if i want get only detail the name in object inspectors?

Comment: just inspector's name?

Comment: I have updated the answer. For  questionerlabel also you can use condition to avoid undefined in your csv.

Comment: hello prachi, in case just inspector name,its still error code, cannot inspectors.name. the sytanx name was error code thx

Comment: The example which you have shown in the question represents it as an object, but in the code, it is showing inspectors as an array. So, inspectors.name will only work in the case of an object type, not an array type. Did your inspector type change?

Comment: so the solution, i must change inspectors from array to object?

Comment: No, you have to tell me first that whether your inspector variable will be an array consisting of multiple objects or just a single-valued object?

Comment: public inspector: Inspector[];

Comment: But in the example you have shown inspector variable as "inspectors": {
      "id": 67,
      "employeeNumber": "18001",
      "name": "Larks Anderson",
      "isActive": true
    },

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174005/discussion-between-prachi-and-t-m).

Answer (score 2):

Use `JSON.stringify(object)`, that'll turn your object into human-readable JSON. Not really sure that's what you want, though.

Answer (score 0):

Below is best answer for resolving undefined and [object object] error

```
          yourdata.forEach((x, len) => {
            if (x.length === undefined) {
              x.values = JSON.stringify(x.values);
            }
            else {

              let nfvdata = "";
              let nfvobject = {};
              x.forEach(y => {
                if (typeof (y) === "string") {
                  nfvobject["questioners"] = y;

                }
                else if (y["questioners"] == undefined) {
                  nfvdata = nfvdata + JSON.stringify(y)
                  nfvobject["questionerDetails"] = nfvdata;
                }

                else {
                  //yourdata.push(y);
                }

              });
               yourdata.splice(len, 1, nfvobject);
              // yourdata.push(nfvobject);
            }
          });
          let record = yourdata[1] == undefined ? dataSet["data"] : dataSet["data"][1];
          this.csvOptions.headers = Object.keys(record);
          new AngularCsv(yourdata, this.Filename, this.csvOptions);
```

this another approach to process JSON as like your's

```
 yourdata.forEach((x, len) => {
            if (x.length === undefined) {
              x.values = JSON.stringify(x.values);
            }
            else {
              yourdata.splice(len, 1);
              x.forEach(y => {
                yourdata.push(y);
              })
            }
          });

          let record = yourdata[1] == undefined ? yourdata : yourdata[1];
          this.csvOptions.headers = Object.keys(record);
          new AngularCsv(dataSet["data"], this.Filename, this.csvOptions);
        }
```